# React-Intl: Message not formatting in Safari

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I have the following translation:

```
{count, number} {count, plural, one {Kundenbewertung} other {Kundenbewertungen}}
```

In Chrome it displays `23 Kundenbewertungen` just fine but in Safari it displays the translation string and throws the error

> Error formatting message: "pdp:product-title:ratings" for locale: "de"
>
> Cannot format message: "pdp:product-title:ratings", using message source as fallback.

In my React Component the code is the following:

```
<FormattedMessage
  id="pdp:product-title:ratings"
  values={{ count: product.metadata.rating.count }}
/>
```

I am totally lost, because it works as expected in Chrome. Am I using the syntax correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason is that [Intl.PluralRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/PluralRules) it not available on Safari. Just use this [polyfill](https://github.com/eemeli/intl-pluralrules) and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

This is a much better polyfill, recommended by MDN and used by polyfill.io: https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-pluralrules/